# Is there a way to display a black screen in Lastfm on Xbox360?

Tags: xbox-360

Question says it all.  I don't want the pictures displaying, don't wanna see artist bios, just want a black screen.  Unfortunately audio goes through the tv, so I can't just turn it off.

Any suggestions or do I have to manually turn my TV brightness up and down to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using component video, you can disconnect all but the red and white audio cables.

If you're using HDMI, you're probably out of luck unless you have a home theater receiver in between the XBox and the TV

Comment: That's what I thought.  Just making sure there wasnt missed a menu option anywhere.